# How to allow Argo workflows (Kind cluster) worker containers to access host ports?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, kind

For local development, we'd like to allow Argo workflows worker containers to access ports on the host, similarly to host mode networking in docker. How can this be achieved? (we deploy Argo on top of a Kind cluster)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not host networking, but nonetheless a solution that answers my needs; it is possible to specify custom docker networks for Kind:

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/pull/1538