# How can I let Kind nodes reference services running on the host (localhost)

Tags: kubernetes, kind

We have a Kind cluster that we use for local development. Various services run in containers, such as DB, backend API, web frontend, etc.., while developers may opt to run one or more services directly on their host for ease of development. Those services running on the host may still be depended on by services that run in the cluster, so I need some method to do two-way networking: Not just from the host into the cluster, but also from the cluster back to the host.

I found a related answer, that seems to hold part of the solution: [How to allow Argo workflows (Kind cluster) worker containers to access host ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563169/how-to-allow-argo-workflows-kind-cluster-worker-containers-to-access-host-port) But I did not get it to work with only this environment variable and there seem to be no follow-up instructions.

We *did* have a solution that worked using Docker for Desktop on Mac, which relied on defining services that run on the host like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  # This points the kubernetes "api" service to api running
  # on the host (outside of docker)
  externalName: host.docker.internal
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3030
```

But the `host.docker.internal` name is not available outside Docker for Desktop, while we need a cross-platform solution that works with Kind.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a straightforward way.  The linked question suggests that whatever host-OS-specific path reaches the host system works in Minikube too, but that there isn't necessarily a fixed DNS name.  If you can use Minikube instead of Kind that does have [a standard host name](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/#hostminikubeinternal) `host.minikube.internal`.

Comment: I ended up solving it by simply replacing `host.docker.internal` with `172.17.0.1`.